# Ввод двух чисел и проверка на то, является ли данный символ числом

Tags: c#

Есть задача

- Запрос числа 1 (ввод с клавиатуры)
- Запрос числа 2 (ввод с клавиатуры)
- Вывод суммы этих чисел
- Вынести данный алгоритм в отдельный метод

В случае не валидного ввода данных (любой символ, отличны от числа) – вывод сообщения на
экран, о том, что введенный символ не является числом и снова попросить пользователя ввести
число.
Как реализовать проверку введенных символов?

```
Console.Write("Введите число 1 "); 
int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
Console.Write("Введите число2 "); 
int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
int с = a + b; 
Console.WriteLine("Сумма чисел = {0}", +с);
```

Comment: `double.TryParse`

Comment: Это что? Код - в вопрос. `int.TryParse`

Comment: Я понимаю как суммировать, но как действовать дальше мне не понятно

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 2):

```
input1:
Console.Write("Введите число 1 ");
bool check_a = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int a);
if (!check_a) goto input1;
input2:
Console.Write("Введите число2 ");
bool check_b = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int b);
if (!check_b) goto input2;
int с = a + b;
Console.WriteLine("Сумма чисел = {0}", +с);
```

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Первое с чего я начал: создал метод, который проверяет введенное значение. Назовем его `IsDigitInput(string value)`. В параметр этот метод будет получать `string` и проверять его с помощью метода `double.TryParse`. Такой подход не самый удачный, поскольку `double.TryParse` нам возвращает помимо проверки само число (если парсинг прошел успешно и строка может быть преобразована в число), но так как Вы только учитесь не стоит забивать голову лишним.

```
private static bool IsDigitInput(string value)
{
    double number;
    bool isDigit = double.TryParse(value, out number);

    return isDigit;
}
```

**2.** Теперь нам нужно получить ввод пользователя. Для этого создадим метод `Input(string messageToUser)`. Результатом выполнения метода будет тип данных `double` (потому что пользователь может захотеть ввести число с запятой). Параметр `messageToUser` нужен для вывода на экран.

```
private static double Input(string messageToUser)
{
    //1. Объявим переменную, в нее будет записано число, если это возможно.
    double number;

    //2. Вводится число с клавиатуры и записывается в переменную value
    Console.Write(messageToUser);
    string value = Console.ReadLine();


    //3. Проверяется введенное значение при помощи ранее созданного метода IsDigitInput
    bool isDigit = IsDigitInput(value);

    //Если метод возвратил нам true
    if (isDigit == true)
    {
        //то парсим полученное с клавиатуры значение value в тип double
        number = double.Parse(value);

        //Возвращаем это число. После этой строки кода метод прервется и мы получим какое-то число в методе Main
        return number;
    }
    //4. Если метод возвратил false
    else
    {
        //Выводим сообщение о том, что ввод некорректный.
        Console.WriteLine("Число было введено не корректно.");
        
        //Возвращаем метод Input. 
        //Метод начнет свое выполнение с самого начала и (т.е перейдет к пункту 1 в этом методе, там где мы number объявили. )
        //Если непонятно, как это работает - погуглите "Рекурсия C#"
        return Input(messageToUser);
    }
}
```

**3.** И последний шаг - метод суммирования. Возвращает сумму двух чисел `a` и `b`, которые были поданы в аргументы метода

```
private static double Sum(double a, double b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Перейдем к использованию всего нашего кода следующим образом:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //получаем первое значение с клавиатуры (если непонятно как - см. пункт 2)
    double a = Input("Введите первое число: ");
    Console.WriteLine();

    //получаем второе значение с клавиатуры
    double b = Input("Введите второе число: ");
    Console.WriteLine();

    //Выводим результат, который получаем из метода Sum
    double sum = Sum(a, b);
    Console.WriteLine("Результат выполнения: {0}", sum);
}
```